# How to change property value in JavaScript using built in function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to simply change the value of someones age which is a property value inside an object i have by clicking a button. I thought this seemed like it should work??

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="incrementAge()">Click me</button>

<script>
var person = {
    name:"Rich",
    age:25, 
    eyeColor:"blue"
};
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.name + " " + person.age;


function incrementAge(){
    return person.age += 1
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sooo? It *does* work and change the property. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: What are you returning a value to?

Comment: Of course, you may want to re-render the `person` into `#demo` after mutating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will also need to reset the content of your element on the page:

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="incrementAge()">Click me</button>

<script>
var person = {
    name:"Rich",
    age:25, 
    eyeColor:"blue"
};



function incrementAge(){
    person.age += 1;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.name + " " + person.age;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML is not binded to the HTML view.

The value is changing but you are not displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the new age to show. If so, you will need to update the innerHTML with that

```
function incrementAge(){
    person.age += 1;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.name + " " + person.age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is actually working as you describe, but the effect is different from what you expect.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.name + " " + person.age;
```

^ This is not a transient expression of constant state. There is nothing in your code to say "Always let this be the case."; it will make that change once and not again. What you should be doing is putting this in a `refreshNameAge()` function, and calling it after any function that might change a person's name and age. Alternatively, you could use `Object.defineProperty` to tie it into a property getter/setter, although that would end up being more complicated.